# SQL IN query from multiple tables

Tags: sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT addresses.email FROM addresses 
WHERE addresses.user_id IN (SELECT  user_group.id_user_groups FROM user_group
WHERE id_group_groups IN (SELECT news_group.groupid_newsg FROM news_group 
WHERE newsid_news_good=1))
```

The above mentioned  SQL query is not executing! It gets hanged until I stop the query. I have tried SQL operator "UNION" after first SELECT statement, but it displays all the email addresses which does not belong to a group. I want to select only those email addresses of the users who belong to "id_group_groups =5" (pls see the query below ) and are subscribed to "newsid_news_good=1".

The following query runs perfectly fine:

```
SELECT DISTINCT addresses.email FROM addresses 
WHERE addresses.user_id IN (SELECT user_group.id_user_groups FROM user_group 
WHERE id_group_groups =5 )
```

Does anybody have an idea what is the problem with the first query? Help will be strongly appreciated!

Comment: Did you mean for them to be nested like that? The problem here is that the nested subquery needs to be evaluated once for every row in `user_group`, which in turn needs to be evaluated once for every row in `addresses`.

Comment: Look at using a `JOIN` instead.

Comment: Yes, I want to execute that query, is the syntax correct? because the other query is perfectly fine as i have checked the result. I have tried with JOIN but i do not know how to write JOIN for more than 2 tables. Is JOIN works with only 2 tables?

Comment: What SQL engine are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the sub selects complicate your problem. If I understand it right, it would be easier to solver your problem using joins instead of sub selects.

Try out something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT addresses.email
FROM addresses
JOIN user_group
    ON user_group.id_user_groups = adresses.USER_ID
JOIN news_group
    ON news_group.groupid_newsg = user_group.id_group_groups
WHERE newsid_news_good = 1
```

Comment: Hello , Tom! Thank you so much Tom, your query worked. I am so happy now! You are great! Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Consider giving an upvote or marking the answer as valid, if it has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT addresses.email FROM addresses 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  user_group.id_user_groups FROM user_group
    INNER JOIN news_group
    ON news_group.groupid_newsg = id_group_groups
    WHERE newsid_news_good=1
)
ON user_group.id_user_groups = addresses.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use joins. The subqueries you are using are most likely the cause of your performance woes.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.email 
FROM addresses a
INNER JOIN user_group u ON u.id_user_groups AND u.id_group_groups = 5
INNER JOIN news_group n ON n.groupid_newsg = u.id_group_groups AND n.newsid_news_good = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you are using MySQL, because it does a really poor job of executing subqueries in unions.  The canonical way to fix this is to change them to `exists` with correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.email
FROM addresses a
where exists (select 1
              from user_group ug 
              where ug.id_user_groups = a.user_id and
                    exists (select 1
                            from news_group ng
                            where ng.newsid_news_good = 1 and
                                  ng.groupid_news = ug.id_group_groups
                           )
             )
```

This solution works in all databases, of course; it is much more efficient in MySQL.  Assuming email is not repeated in the addresses table, then you can drop the outer distinct.

The alternatives with `join` are also feasible.  However they require the distinct.